# Building and running a java application from Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, build, compilation

I've recently started using NetBeans, coming from Eclipse.

I have a simple implementation of SnakeYaml (a yaml parser for java) I am trying to test. It is contained in a main method.

When I try to run it (F6) like I would in Eclipse, I get a successful build but no output. Instead, to run my program, I need to first build (F11), then run (F6). Is there a way for my project to be automatically built when I try to run it.

*Note:* Netbeans actually tells me I don't have to build to run from inside the IDE, but it seems to be lying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MaxMackie not an answer

1) project -> properties -> compiling -> Compile on Save - mark checked

2) project -> properties -> Run -> select main.class (because your project can contains tons Java Classes that contains main method too)

last property is to set current project as main project (i never ever to needed to check or set that) and check tools -> options -> keymap

[image]

Comment: Did both, however I still need to build before seeing different output.

Comment: question: are you imported this project from WorkSpace (eclipse), then to try Re-Synchronize Eclipse Project

Comment: No, this project was made from scratch in Netbeans.

Comment: there must be another problem (betweens hands & head) please take this code http://stackoverflow.com/q/8249353/714968, and set that as main class, hmmm maybe ... but I still use version 6.9.1, I'm surprised, because NetBean is anti-technocrati IDE, created for total lazy coders, that can't care about nothing

Comment: I'm using version 6.8 on Linux if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have set the project as the main project and the keys are correctly mapped....this is very weird.

Comment: btw you are lucky man, any down-votes, nor voting for close this question, please after succeed or not to delete this question :-)

Comment: hehehe let it be you have half-sized NetBeans IDE, why not, crazy thread, delete this thread, and to check Unix/Linux Forums, maybe there are some issue with openJDK, huuuh then make me this funny *** totally crazy too :-)

Comment: hahaha, I will wait a bit longer to see if anyone can help. If not, I will delete. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your answer led me to figure a hack around my problem. I disabled "Compile on save", now I can F6 and compile+run. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Shift+F6 or `Run-->Run File`(when the Class with the main method is opened and in the current editor)

Comment: maybe you could try setting `Run --> Main Project --> None` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/525675/344927) and then try this ?

Comment: Still getting old output, I need to re-build to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make Sure that the class lies in the project's package.
2. `main()` method should be having the correct lines which are to be executed.