# GUI functions work when running from IDE, but not when running jar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jar

Is there any normal reason that a GUI would work when launched by running code from, say, Netbeans, but have trouble when launched from a .jar? If I launch my program from Netbeans via Run, it works fine. All buttons work, their functionality works and all is well. I do a clean and build, and when i then run the .jar, one of the buttons stops working, and all the functionality put into buttons and fields stops working.

In case there's no easy answer to this problem, is there a way to see an error log from a jar file?

Comment: As to logs, configure your logger system so that it spout everything to stdout. BTW, which OS is that? If Unix-like, is the `DISPLAY` environment variable set?

Answer (score 3):

Open a command prompt, and use

```
java -jar youJarFile.jar
```

Unhandled Exceptions will display in the CLI/terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings of your IDE, check which classpath is used, which JDK, which settings.

Run the jar from the commandline to see errormessages.

your jar may also lack a Manifest file which could make your jar clickable to start the application.

Answer (score 1):

you should to set--->

1) right mouse click on Project, last option is Properties

2) in the Run select from drop-down proper Main-class

3) maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262793/building-and-running-a-java-application-from-netbeans/8263013#8263013) thread will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you have written all code yourself, you can make use of assertions or the Logger API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html

this shoul aid in getting to the root cause...

Answer (score 0):

Look into the PATH variable of your system and see whether the path to your
JRE is included, and if it's the same as the one that your IDE is using.